# How do I save a input String into a textfile with output messages?

Tags: java, file, text-files

Im trying to get 4 strings on terminal as output where you have to input text and that text will be saved in a .txt file, but what happens is that the strings which are supposed to output on terminal gets inputted in the txt file. Here is my code

```
    import easyIO.*;

    class Birds {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            In press = new In();
            Out birds = new Out("birdfile.txt", true);

            birds.out("Birds name: ");
            String biName = press.inLine();

            birds.out("Sex: ");
            String biSex = press.inLine();

            birds.out("Place for observation: ");
            String plObs = press.inLine();

            birds.out("Date of observation: ");
            int date = press.inInt();

            birds.close(); 
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how i can get the Strings Birds name, Sex, Place for observation, Date of observation as output on terminal then what you input in the output gets saved in the textfile?

Because now the output messages gets saved in the textfile.

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

Thanks alot for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put any variables you want to print into a `System.out.println()` if you want it to print to terminal.

For example:

```
System.out.println("Birds name: " + biName);
```

If `biName` was say "Crow" then that `println` statement would print

*Birds name: Crow*

The problem causing output and not input only being is because that's all all you are telling `brids.out()` to write to the file.

You can change it so it writes the bird's name instead of printing the "Birds Name:" text.

```
System.out.print("Birds Name: ");     //prints "Birds name: " to terminal
String biName = press.inLine();       //capture user input
birds.out(biName);                    //write captured input to file
```

This will both print to terminal and write to file.

Comment: I see, when I run the program now it appears blank until I for example write "Crow" then the next line says Birds name: Crow. I want the program to write "Birds name: " then if I write Crow in that String it gets saved to text file. You know how to do that?

Comment: You just want the birds name saved by itself?

Comment: I've edited that last block of code, see if that is what you meant.

Comment: umm.. "Birds name:" should appear instantly when i run the program then i can just write in "Crow" in "Birds name:" and it gets saved. Because now i need to write "Crow" then "Birds name: Crow" appears after that. I want it to say "Birds name:" then i can input "Crow" in that field.

Comment: Ok I changed my answer at the bottom. That will print "birds name" instantly, and then you can enter "Crow" and it will write that to file. If the answer works remember to upvote and accept the answer as the correct answer

Comment: im relative new here, and upvoting requires 15 in reputation. I accepted the answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

You have the roles of classes `In` and `Out` somewhat reversed. Change `new In()` to `new In("birdfile.txt")`. For console output, I agree with redFIVE that you should just use `System.out.println`.

Comment: My answer was related to a different problem entirely, which was that he was using class `In` incorrectly. He also does want it outputted to the console: "Im trying to get 4 strings on terminal as output...the strings which are supposed to output on terminal". Please undo your downvote if possible.